# Contacts not entering JB

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am using a Fire Event Run once(Manually) option to trigger my JB interaction. My contacts only enter any journey when at start i wipe out the Data extension records and freshly insert the records. I am only using one data extension for all the interactions and have to delete the records form the DE every time the Fire Event is executed . Unable to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour that you are experiencing is intentional.

When you Fire an Event (either from an Automation or by scheduling it in the Event itself), then a "high watermark" is added to the Data Extension. For example, if you have 50 records in your DE and fire the Event, all 50 records will be injected into the Interaction (providing they meet the Contact Filter Criteria defined in the Event). At this time a "high watermark" is added to the DE.

Let's say you add another 6 records to the DE. The next time that the Event is fired, only those 6 records will enter the Interaction, as it checks the high watermark.

If you need all records in a DE to re-enter the Interaction each time, then you need to write a Query Activity to overwrite the Event Source DE prior to firing the event. This will reset the high watermark and cause all records to enter the Interaction.